# Extract only the number in reverse till a non-numeric character is reached in a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario to extract vehicle number from plates, to match with a standard database which has consistent numbering format i.e SHJ3/43255

Trying to extract the numbers from the end of string, till a non-numeric char is found

For example:

- 27675 should give 27675
- SHJ 1/ 5459 should give 5459
- SHJ60219 should give 60219
- SHJ3.8416 should give 8486
- SJ2.56432 should give 56432

There are exceptional cases too (where above won't work)

- 3972W should give 3972
- 1SHJ1X should give 1

Please help with the regex approach for handling this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight variation, using a single capturing group, and the `digits` class:

```
regexp_replace(your_columns, '^.*?([[:digit:]]+)[^[:digit:]]*$', '\1')
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=140d10965123614346b85fa42372d95b)

Comment: . . I was trying something similar, but it kept returning only one digit.  I think the key is the `?` before the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little more complicated than I originally thought.  You want to match a number *before* a final character, if the character is there.  One method uses `regexp_replace()`:

```
select col, regexp_replace(col, '^.*([^0-9]|^)([0-9]+)[A-Za-z]?$', '\2')
from (select '27675' as col from dual union all
      select 'SHJ 1/ 5459' from dual union all
      select 'SHJ3.8416' from dual union all
      select '3972W' from dual union all
      select '2SHJ1X' from dual) x
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=482e46f1fc3e9e3e82db531c611ae159) is a db<>fiddle.